# python (confused in code, need explanation)

Tags: python

```
list1 = ["xyz", "zara", "Pynative"]
print(max(list1))
```

the output will be zara on the terminal in py charm

please I am having difficulties reading this code, someone should please explain to me

Comment: Last item alphabetically is returned

Comment: why are you confused? what's surprising

Comment: @It_is_Chris that is not correct, "act" would be higher than "Pickle" although it is first alphabeticaly.

Comment: @EliHarold lowercase the `p` Case mattes

Comment: @It_is_Chris I know that case matters, that is precisely why you should know your comment is wrong. "P" and "p" would both alphabetically be after "a" however only one of them is evaluated as higher than "a" by `max`.

Comment: @It_is_Chris `max` compares the `ord()` value of the characters and DOES NOT sort alphabetically.

Comment: @EliHarold Ha, you are getting hung up on the semantics of my five word comment. I also never used the word "sort" so I do not know why you are using it.

Comment: @It_is_Chris actually, I am clarifying so that future readers are not mislead.

Answer (score 0):

The max value of the list is not the last one alphabetically and 'z' is not necessarily the highest (as the other answers and comments have said.

The max function evaluates the `ord()` of the first character so 'z' is the highest in this case, but 'Z'(capital) is not higher than 'x' for example so:

```
list1 = ["xyz", "Zara", "Pynative"]
print(max(list1))
```

gives:

```
xyz
```

hence it's not alphabetical.

Another example for futher clarification:

```
lst = ['test', 'ack', 'Zzzzzck']
print(max(lst))
```

gives:

```
test
```

Because:

```
print(ord('t'))
print(ord('Z'))
print(ord('a'))
```

gives:

```
116 #t is highest
90
97
```

Lastly:

```
lst = ['za3', '{!9zb4']
print(max(lst))
```

gives:

```
{!9zb4
```

because:

```
print(ord('z'))
print(ord('{'))
```

gives:

```
122
123 #{ is higher
```

If the firs character is the same it evaluates the second, and so on.